# Angular 2: How to write a for loop, not a foreach loop

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Using Angular 2, I want to duplicate a line in a template multiple times. Iterating over an object is easy, `*ngFor="let object of objects"`. However, I want to run a simple `for` loop, not a `foreach` loop. Something like (pseudo-code):

```
{for i = 0; i < 5; i++}
  <li>Something</li>
{endfor}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can instantiate an empty array with a given number of entries if you pass an `int` to the `Array` constructor and then iterate over it via `ngFor`.

**In your component code :**

```
export class ForLoop {
  fakeArray = new Array(12);
}
```

**In your template :**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let a of fakeArray; let index = index">Something {{ index }}</li>
</ul>
```

The index properties give you the iteration number.

[Live version](https://embed.plnkr.co/2tpFX9Y26FZ33AmTzJyd/)

Comment: Nice solution, in addition I would wrap the `new Array(i);` in a pipe so that it would be reusable `<li *ngFor="let a of 12 | fakeArray; let index = index">Something {{ index }}</li>`, pipe code: `transform(i: number) { return new Array(i) };`

Answer (score 90):

You could dynamically generate an array of however time you wanted to render `<li>Something</li>`, and then do `ngFor` over that collection. Also you could take use of `index` of current element too.

**Markup**

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of createRange(5); let currentElementIndex=index+1">
      {{currentElementIndex}} Something
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Code**

```
createRange(number){
  // return new Array(number);
  return new Array(number).fill(0)
    .map((n, index) => index + 1);
}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z6WLd9QDOd3EYkNX3rk0?p=preview)

Under the hood angular de-sugared this `*ngFor` syntax to `ng-template` version.

```
<ul>
    <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="createRange(5)" let-currentElementIndex="(index + 1)" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
      {{currentElementIndex}} Something
    </ng-template>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice solution you provide, I'm just astounded how dumb this seems. I just wanted to make a simple for loop, displaying a <p> tag `count : int` amount of times, my property's number is.

Comment: @Esten my bad. I removed the wrong information, thanks for heads up :)

Comment: createRange(number) { return new Array(number); }

Comment: slightly better solution than @HebertLima { return Array.from(new Array(number).keys()); } or { return [...new Array(number).keys()]; } - this way array get values

Comment: @DamianPioś thanks for the suggestion, I have used a suggestion with slight modification.

Answer (score 34):

Depending on the length of the wanted loop, maybe even a more "template-driven" solution:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let index of [0,1,2,3,4,5]">
    {{ index }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the winner for simple iterators

Comment: again, the question simply is for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {}. If there is None, and the only way to do it, is to use an away, .. then that is the answer to the question... not 'how' to generate an array of size n.

Comment: Perfect for small arrays 

Answer (score 30):

You can do both in one if you use `index`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let myIndex = index>
  {{myIndex}}
</div>
```

With this you can get the best of both worlds.

Comment: good suggestion except this requires you to already have an array to loop over or at least count. It doesn't really work if you simply need to loop n times

Comment: This worked for nicely for me on `4.2.4^` still. Just wanted to write this since some Angular 2+ is still in flux. I was looking to just get the iterations of an existing array printed in a table and this is the most succinct and elegant solution (IMO)

Comment: Are you not missing a closing quote here?

Comment: sorry, but -1 for not providing the answer to the question - in the suggested solution, the iteration is on an array and not a number that represents a simple count for the loop.

Answer (score 8):

The better way to do this is creating a fake array in component:

In Component:

```
fakeArray = new Array(12);
```

InTemplate:

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let n of fakeArray">
     MyCONTENT
</ng-container>
```

[Plunkr here](https://embed.plnkr.co/2tpFX9Y26FZ33AmTzJyd/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `_.range([optional] start, end)`. It creates a new Minified list containing an interval of numbers from start (inclusive) until the end (exclusive). Here I am using lodash.js `._range()` method.

Example:

**CODE**

```
var dayOfMonth = _.range(1,32);  // It creates a new list from 1 to 31.
```

//**HTML** Now, you can use it in For loop

```
<div *ngFor="let day of dayOfMonth">{{day}}</div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the statement _No imports required_? Judging from your example it seems you need to `import * as _ from 'lodash'` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
   queNumMin = 23;
   queNumMax= 26;
   result = 0;
for (let index = this.queNumMin; index <= this.queNumMax; index++) {
         this.result = index
         console.log( this.result);
     }
```

Range min and max number

Answer (score 1):

The best answer for this question I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36535705/3695748)

You need to create an attribute inside your class and reference it to Array object:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  Arr = Array; //Array type captured in a variable
  num:number = 20;
}
```

And inside your HTML you can use:

```
<ul id="next-pages">
    <li class="line" *ngFor="let _ of Arr(10)">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

for Example let say you have an array called myArray if you want to iterate over it

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let array of myArray; let i = index">{{i}} {{array}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in a simple way,

```
<div *ngFor="let i of ('a,'.repeat(100).split(','))">
    .....
</div>
```

`('a,'.repeat(100).split(','))` --> it means construct a long concatenated string of `a,` 100 times and then split it by `,` results in array of 100 items, which `ngFor` picks up and iterate 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

**1.generate a pipe for example "ng g p range"**

```
transform(length: number):any[]{
        return new Array(length);
    }
```

**2.in html**

```
 <div *ngFor="let _ of (12|range)" >  ...   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a spread operator in a loop like this, if you're using Angular :

```
this.triggersList = res.content;
      for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
          this.triggersList.push(...this.triggersList);
      }
      this.totalItems = res.totalElements;
```

*Believing the original question could be expanded to the correct use of the engine, populating the html's list all the same.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the object of ith term and input it to another component in each iteration then:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th> Blogs </th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let blogEl of blogs">
    <app-blog-item [blog]="blogEl"> </app-blog-item>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ngfor is correct but question is to range of numbers. similar to for(i=0;i<=5; i++), but this answer is for ngfor rotating objects

Answer (score -5):

If you want duplicate lines multiple time.

You can simply do :-

declare in .ts file

```
public repeater = "<li>Something</li>";
```

Then use following to print it .html file.

```
{{repeater.repeat(5)}}
```