# How can I use NgFor without creating arrays to generate matrix UI pattern

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I would like to implement UI matrix pattern, which should generate dynamically.
By receiving input parameter it should decide what would be UI matrix pattern dimensions:
For example 9X3 elements:
[pattern 9x3 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrr3U.png)

I use Angular2.js, typescript, SCSS.

html tamplate and .ts  looks:

```js
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector   : 'game-pattern',
  moduleId   : module.id,
  templateUrl: 'game-pattern.component.html',
  styleUrls  : ['game-pattern.component.css'],
  directives : [NgFor],
})
export class GamePatternComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('CardType') public cardType: number;

  public horizontalElementLocation: number;
  public verticalElementLocation: number;
  public rows: number[]     = [];
  public elements: number[] = [];
  public y: number;
  public x: number;

 // public cardType = 3;
 constructor() {
    this.cardType = 3;
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    console.log('cardType ' + this.cardType);
    this.chooseGamePattern();
  }

  public chooseGamePattern() {
    if (this.cardType === 3) {
      this.horizontalElementLocation = 9;
      this.verticalElementLocation   = 3;
    }

    for (this.y = 0; this.y < this.verticalElementLocation; this.y++) {
      this.rows[this.y] = 0;
      for (this.x = 0; this.x < this.horizontalElementLocation; this.x++) {
        this.elements[this.x] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="game-pattern" >
  <div class="pattern-row" *ngFor="#row of rows">
    <div class="big-circle" *ngFor="#elemnt of elements"> 
      <div class="small-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

** this code could not run in this environment :)*

**Question:**
How can I use NgFor without creating arrays to generate UI.
I mean, if I will receive input x=9 and y=3 it should build UI matrix pattern of 9X3.
Please advise :)

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use tags that are unrelated to solving your problem (ie. do not use the [sass] tag unless you think a Sass expert is going to be able to help you).

Comment: @D.F. what is a point in nested `for` loop here `for (this.x = 0; this.x < ...` ?

Answer (score 6):

Create custom [`STRUCTURAL DIRECTIVE`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html) which repeats template `N` times.

```
import {TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Directive, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
   selector: '[mgRepeat]'
})
export class mgRepeatDirective {
   constructor(
       private _template: TemplateRef,
       private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
   ) { }

   @Input('mgRepeat')
   set times(times: number) {
       for (let i = 0; i < times; ++i)
           this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._template);
   }
}
```

Use as follows

```
<div id="game-pattern" >
  <div class="pattern-row" *mgRepeat="verticalElementLocation">
     <div class="big-circle" *mgRepeat="horizontalElementLocation"> 
        <div class="small-circle"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I Kept getting `Can't bind to 'mgRepeat' since it isn't a known property of..` because I choose to omit the `mgRepeat` beside the `@Input` **Please note:** `@Input` should have `mgRepeat` or the method name should be `mgRepeat` [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40706065/234110)

Answer (score 4):

Building arrays just to iterate over them seems lavish. Creating a `Directive` to replace `ngFor` is sort of redundant.

Instead you could use a `Pipe` returning an `Iterable` and use it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of 30|times">{{ i }}</div>
```

For an implementation of such a `Pipe` have a look at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46034728/616292) on [Repeat HTML element multiple times using ngFor based on a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number).

Answer (score 2):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of [].constructor(20)">

</ng-container>
```

OR

```
<div *ngFor="let x of 'x '.repeat(lengthFromController + 1).split(' ') let i = index">
      {{i}}
</div>
```

OR better yet

```
<ul>
  <li>Method Fourth</li>
  <li *ngFor='let x of counter(demoLen) ;let i= index'>{{i}}</li>
</ul>

export class AppComponent {
  demoLen = 5 ;
  counter = Array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either create an helper array like shown in [Repeat HTML element multiple times using ngFor based on a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number) using `new Array(count).fill(1)` and use `ngFor` to iterate over this array or you can implement your own structural directive like [NgFor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/directives/ng_for.ts#L71) that doesn't iterate over an array but instead uses a count as input.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i wanted to make a price rating dynamic something like this

'Price Rating : $$$' or 'Price Rating : $$' without making an array to repeat this "$"

so i knew that my rating is 5 at most 
and this working well for me .

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | slice: 0:place.priceRating">
      $
   </ng-container>
```

priceRating maybe from 0 to 5

hope that help

Answer (score 0):

After reading all answers I managed to solve it:

```
 public chooseGamePattern() {
    if (this.cardType === 3) {
        this.horizontalElementLocation = 9;
        this.verticalElementLocation = 3;
        this.rows = new Array(this.verticalElementLocation);
        this.elements = new Array(this.horizontalElementLocation);
    }
```

It works for me.
Thank You all!!!