# Angular2 Can't bind to DIRECTIVE since it isn't a known property of element

Tags: angular, typescript, directive

I generated new @Directive by Angular CLI, it was imported it to my app.module.ts

```
import { ContenteditableModelDirective } from './directives/contenteditable-model.directive';

import { ChatWindowComponent } from './chat-window/chat-window.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContenteditableModelDirective,
    ChatWindowComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

and I try to use in my component (ChatWindowComponent)

```
<p [appContenteditableModel] >
    Write message
</p>
```

even if within directive is only Angular CLI generated code:

```
 import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

 @Directive({
   selector: '[appContenteditableModel]'
 })
 export class ContenteditableModelDirective {

 constructor() { }

 }
```

I got the error:

**zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'appContenteditableModel' since it isn't a known property of 'p'.**

I tried almost every possible changes, following this [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) everything should work but it does not.

Any help?

Comment: The result I need is `[(appContenteditableModel)]="draftMessage.text"` at the end...

Comment: Then try like this `<p [appContenteditableModel]="draftMessage.text"></p>`

Comment: It works without brackets `appContenteditableModel="draftMessage.text"` and also `(appContenteditableMode)l="draftMessage.text"` resolve the promise rejection but it also seems to do not pass the variable

Answer (score 234, accepted):

When wrapping a property in brackets `[]` you're trying to bind to it. So you have to declare it as an `@Input`.

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
 selector: '[appContenteditableModel]'
})
export class ContenteditableModelDirective {

  @Input()
  appContenteditableModel: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

The important part is, that the member (`appContenteditableModel`) needs to be named as the property on the DOM node (and, in this case, the directive selector).

Comment: I have input `@Input ('appContenteditableModel') model : any;` and also output  `@Output ('appContenteditableModel') update : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();` in my directive. It seems that the model works well but the emitter called by `this.update.emit(value)` does not change the value in parent component. What I do wrong? `[(appContenteditableModel)]="draftMessage.text"`

Comment: Actually I try to "simulate" [(ngModel)] outside of <input> element

Comment: `@Output` is for emitting events only. If you want to keep the value in sync with the parent's, you may consider adding the `@HostBinding` annotation.

Comment: If I undersand well `@HostBinding` will help to keep the value in sync within the html element, am I right? This element I need to be edited by user `contenteditable="true"` so that input I need to keep in sync with the variable in the same component.

Comment: if using strict mode and your directive requires no value, you need to do `appContenteditableModel = undefined`;

Comment: Ah thank you.  In case someone else runs into it, my specific issue was that the directive selector (e.g. `selector: 'fooDirective'`) didn't match the `@Input()` property name (e.g. `@Input() barDirective`).  I renamed the selector, but didn't think about the property too.

Comment: String did not work for me as I was using no value for the attribute, used any and it worked, I know i have to give a value for attribute but, that was my case.

Comment: "The important part is, that the member (appContenteditableModel) needs to be named as the property on the DOM node (and, in this case, the directive selector)" - holy cow, didn't find it in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 56):

If you're using a shared module to define the directive make sure it is both declared **and exported** by the module it's defined in.

```
// this is the SHARED module, where you're defining directives to use elsewhere
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [NgIfEmptyDirective, SmartImageDirective],
  exports: [NgIfEmptyDirective, SmartImageDirective]
})
```

Comment: and what if they are not in the same module?

Comment: @OhadSadan I'm not sure exactly what you mean. This is an example of when you *don't* have them in the same module, and I'm just saying make sure to declare AND export directives if you're creating them in a shared module (which you must then then import them into a different module).

Comment: In your 'main' module you only need to import the 'directives module' and then all your components can see them.

Comment: This is a minute detail but often missed. Thank you !

Comment: Thanks, I declared the directive and forgot to export it in the shared :)

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same issue with a directive declared in a shared module. I'm using this directive to disable a form control.

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDisableControl]'
})
export class DisableControlDirective {

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) { }

  @Input('disableControl') set disableControl( condition: boolean) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    this.ngControl.control[action]();
  }

}
```

To work it properly, declare and export the directive in shared module (or any module you are using).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DisableControlDirective } from './directives/disable-control/disable-control.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DisableControlDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [DisableControlDirective],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Now we can use this directive in any module where we are importing **SharedModule**. 
Now to disable a reactive form's control, we can use it like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" formControlName="userName" appDisableControl [disableControl]="disable" />
```

Mistake I was doing it, I was using only selector (appDisableControl) and passing the disable param to this. but to pass an input param, we have to use it like above.

Answer (score 6):

For me the fix was moving the directive references from root `app.module.ts` (the lines for `import`, `declarations`, and/or `exports`) to the more specific module `src/subapp/subapp.module.ts` my component belonged to.

Comment: WTF ??????? any explanation for that ?? and it worked after 2 hours !

Answer (score 4):

In sum, because your directive looks like an [anchor directive](http://angular-dev.chigix.com/guide/dynamic-component-loader#the-anchor-directive), remove the brackets and it would work.

Actually, I have not found the corresponding sections related to when the brackets should be removed or not, where only one mention I've found is located at the section on [dynamic components](http://angular-dev.chigix.com/guide/dynamic-component-loader#loading-components):

> Apply that to `<ng-template>` **without the square brackets**

, which is however not perfectly covered in the [Attribute Directives](http://angular-dev.chigix.com/guide/attribute-directives) document.

Individually, I agree with you and was thinking that `[appContenteditableModel]` should be equal to `appContenteditableModel` and angular template parser might work around whether there is `@input()` data binding or not automatically, as well. But they seem exactly not processed equally under the hood, even in current Angular Version of 7.

Answer (score -1):

If you have sub modules other than app-module then declare the directive under that sub module or modules in the following way

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      ContenteditableModelDirective
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [

      ContenteditableModelDirective
    ],
    providers: [
        
    ]
})
```