# Conditionally Apply Custom Directive

Tags: angular

I created a custom Angular directive called `myRequiredDirective`. I want to conditionally apply it to an input control similar to how it can be done with `[required]`:

```
<input class="form-control" [required]="false" />
```

However, when I try to do something similar with my `myRequiredDirective`, I get an error: `Can't bind to 'myRequiredDirective' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.`

#### directive.ts

```
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, Validators, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myRequiredDirective]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MyRequiredDirective, multi: true }]
})

export class MyRequiredDirective implements Validator {

    private valFn = CustomValidator();

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        return this.valFn(control);
    }

}

function CustomValidator(): ValidatorFn {

    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
        let isValid = true;

        if (!control.value) {
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (control.value == 0) {
            // Set control invalid if value equals zero. Mainly used for drop downs where the default value is usually 0.
            isValid = false;
        }

        return isValid ? null : { 'required': 'message will come from validators.component.html' };
    };
}
```

Is there a way I can make my custom directive behave similar to `[required]`?

#### Edit #1

I solved the `Can't bind to 'myRequiredDirective' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.` by doing the following:

```
export class MyRequiredDirective implements Validator {

    @Input() myRequiredDirective: boolean;
    
    private valFn = CustomValidator(this.myRequiredDirective); // this.myRequiredDirective is undefined

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        return this.valFn(control);
    }

}
```

and in the HTML template:

```
<input class="form-control" [myRequiredDirective]="false" />
```

However, `this.myRequiredDirective` is undefined when I try to pass it into the CustomValidator.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705819/angular2-cant-bind-to-directive-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-element

Comment: @David thanks, that fixes the `Can't bind to 'myRequiredDirective' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.` error. However, when I try: `<input class="form-control" [myRequiredDirective]="false" />`, my directive still runs and sets the input as required. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't seem to be checking for that value you pass to the directive to see if the control is required or not

Comment: @David see my Edit #1 in the question above. How do I get the value being passed in from my HTML template?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<input *ngIf="!condition4directive" class="form-control"/>
<input *ngIf="condition4directive" class="form-control" myRequiredDirective/>
```