# Looping over a non-array variable with ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-directive

In my `app.component.ts`I have a variable of type `number` like so

`somevar: number = 3`

I am trying to loop over it in my `app.component.html` and do something three time (in this case, since somevar is 3).

Is this possible since the variable is not an array in which case this would be trivial using the `ngIf` directive.

I tried something like below -but that's pretty idiotic and doesn't work, of course.

```
<div *ngFor="let i = somevar; while i > 0; i--">
   <span>+</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i know its not the perfect solution but you could create and empty array of length somevar and iterate over that also I checked angulars documentation and it says int works only for iterables

Comment: Take a look at [How can I use NgFor without creating arrays to generate matrix UI pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36621771/1009922).

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I used that approach for another  similar scenario.  Was just wondering if there is another way that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it wihouth adding a method or an array variable in the component class. It creates a string by repeating a character `somevar` times, and converts the string to an array of characters, which can be iterated with `ngFor`.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of 'x'.repeat(somevar).split('')">
   <span>+</span>
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2s8dmi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.