# *ngFor iterating the values of the array

Tags: angular, typescript

I created star rating system. In the `Rate` property, I keep the rating on a scale of 1 to 5. I assigned the `Rate` property to an `Stars` array in which these values are. 

I have a problem with correctly displaying values from the table. For example, the rating value is 5 and should display 5 stars and in my case it displays only 3. How to solve it? 
[image]
***Component:***

```
 export class RatingStarComponent implements OnInit {

  commentList: Rating[];
  stars: number[];
  constructor(private productService: CategoriesProductsService, private router: Router ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getComment().subscribe(data => {
      this.commentList = data;
      this.commentList = this.commentList.filter(x => x.ProductId === this.products.Id);
      this.stars = this.commentList.map(x => x.Rate);
      console.log('Comment List:', this.commentList);
      console.log('Stars:', this.stars);
    });
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let comment of commentList">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   Comment: {{comment.Comment}} <br/> 
   Your rating: {{comment.Rate}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" >
    <ul class="list-inline ratingList" *ngFor="let x of stars">
      <li >
          <i value="x"  class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or sugestion is welcome

Comment: are you getting correct data in   this.stars = this.commentList.map(x => x.Rate);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I repeat \*ngFor an arbitrary number of times using built in angular directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251160/can-i-repeat-ngfor-an-arbitrary-number-of-times-using-built-in-angular-directiv)

Comment: @AkberIqbal this is not a duplicate, at least try to understand the question before flagging... op has a problem with its logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not 3, it's the length of your comments array. You are iterating over the array of 3 items, it will always be 3 stars if there are 3 comments.

Add stars property to your comments:

```
this.commentList = this.commentList.map(comment => Object.assign(comment, {stars: new Array(comment.Rate)}));
```

And iterate separately for every comment:

```
<ul class="list-inline ratingList" *ngFor="let x of comment.stars">
  <li >
    <i value="x"  class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

---

You could probably make a `toArray` pipe to return an array from the `Rate` number and use it like this:

`*ngFor="let x of (comment.Rate | toArray)"`

That way you won't need to mutate your `commentList` array like this:

`// this.commentList = this.commentList
 //        .map(comment => Object.assign(comment, {stars: new Array(comment.Rate)}));`

Pipe will return an array of length from the number (Rate in your example):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'toArray'})
export class ToArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): any[] {
    return new Array(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, then they should expose a function to get an array from a number and keep in mind that they should not call functions from template without `OnPush` since they will get triggered on each change detection cycle, or build a pipe to pipe a number to an array. But they are obviously new to angular and this is the easiest way.

Comment: it doesn't solve op problem. He wants to display 5 stars and color x of them based on the `comment.Rate`. + building a pipe is indeed a nice and elegant solution, I'd definetly upvote such an answer, however a bit harder to explain to a newcomer...

Comment: @Florian I don't think you have understood the question. He wants just to display x number of stars.

Comment: hmm indeed, looks like I extrapolated. +1 for promoting pipe ! I'm a bit sad you don't return an `iterator` :p

Answer (score 0):

Change the `value` attribute in `i` like this

```
<i value="x"  class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i>
```

to

```
<i [value]="x"  class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i>
```

because your x value is dynamic to bind the dynamic value you need to use `[]`brackets

Answer (score 0):

You need 5 but getting 3 because of your `this.stars` Array

This is how I handled a similar case in my app.
`this.starWidth = this.rating * 75 / 5;`

#### html

```
<div [style.width.px]="starWidth" >
      <div style="width: 75px">
        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

probably, in your case

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let comment of commentList">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
           Comment: {{comment.Comment}} <br/> 
           Your rating: {{comment.Rate}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6" >
            <div [style.width.px]="comment.Rate * 75 / 5 " >
                <div style="width: 75px">
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```