# parse Array in angular template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

somebody maybe encounter some situation when use the `ngFor` without collections.But seems looks like every one like to set the variable of `array` and let `*ngFor` binding like following code:

**array**

```
// typescript

public bignumber:number[]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

//html

<ng-template *ngFor="let item of bignumber | index as i">
  p {{i}}
  <!-- would show ten times -->
</ng-template>
```

It's not friendly for template when you want to run 5 times or 10 times and you need to set the new varible then you can iterator.So I want to use `Array` new `Array` in template but it didn't work.No matter `new Array()` or any you would use the keyword `Array`, it would parse the our variable but not the specify keyword.

**error log**

> ERROR TypeError: _co.Array is not a function

Now I use the complex way to solve this situation:

**template**

```
<ng-template [ngForOf]="[].map.call({length:10},[].map).fill('')" let-i="index">
  p {{i}}
  <!-- show 10 times -->
</ng-template>
```

Is any possible use the cleary code like:

```
[ngForOf]="Array(10).fill()"
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Angular doesn't support `Array` constructor in template.

To work around it you could try the following:

**Template only solutions**

1) `[].constructor(10)`

2) `String.prototype.repeat()`

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of ' '.repeat(2).split(''), let i = index ">
  p {{i}}
</ng-container>
```

3) Using  `ngTemplateOutlet`

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tmpl; context: { $implicit: 0 }"></ng-container>


<ng-template #tmpl let-i>
  <div>
    Your template here {{ i }}
  </div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="i < 10">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tmpl; context { $implicit: i + 1 }"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

3) Using `NgIf`

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="1; then tmpl"></ng-container>

<ng-template #tmpl let-i>
  <div>
    Your template here {{ i }}
  </div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="i < 10">
      <ng-container *ngIf="i + 1, then tmpl"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

**Declaring Array property on component**

You can also create `Array` property on your component:

```html
export class AppComponent  {
  Array = Array;
}
```

and then

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of Array.apply(null, Array(2)), let i = index ">
  p {{i}}
</ng-container>

<br>

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of Array(2).fill(), let i = index ">
  p {{i}}
</ng-container>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rykee4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

And you can always create your own pipe:

See also

- [Repeat HTML element multiple times using ngFor based on a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number/36535705#36535705)

Comment: Is any different that set variable in typescript?

Comment: Did you mean `Array = Array;`?

Comment: Angular doesn't support `Array` constructor in template. Only one way to do it working is to define property on component

Comment: I want to solve  problem is clear in template ,if I use this method in other component that need to add ‘Array=Array’ every single time