# Run ngFor several times

Tags: angular, angular7, ngfor

I'm using Angular 7.

I got a an array and I'm doing the usual `ngFor` in the HTML:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let card of cardNames">
```

Is there a way to iterate over the `cardNames` elements more than once?

Comment: just use another ngFor?

Comment: Can you include a sample? IE if you had `["A", "B", "C"]`, what you like the output to be?

Comment: @Antoniossss can ngfor be nested somehow? can you show an example?

Comment: @Vlad274 if the array was with "a", "b", "c", i want it to either iterate like this: abcabc or like this: aabbcc

Comment: `<div *ngFor=...><div *ngFor=....></div></div>` ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat HTML element multiple times using ngFor based on a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "if the array was with "a", "b", "c", i want it to either iterate like this: abcabc or like this: aabbcc"

Heres a weird one for you with the `*ngFor`, use repeat and split to determine how many time you want the array to repeat and then within that show the array you would like. Weird but gives what you want.

```
public fetchData = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Then in the template. The 2 is the count for how many time's you want to repeat the nested `*ngFor`.

```
<div *ngFor = "let x of ' '.repeat(2).split('')">
  <div *ngFor="let titlee of fetchData">
      {{ titlee }}
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives printed in DOM.

```
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

Im not 100% sure as to if this has any associated problems with it, just one way of getting to the answer you are looking for.

[Repeat HTML element multiple times using ngFor based on a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number).

For the second way, just be lazy I guess. Instead of iterating of the array with the values you want iterating one. Make a new array, for each index of the old array push it to the new one twice. Then iterate over it as usual with a standard `*ngFor`

```
  public fetchData = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  public dupedData = [];

  public ngOnInit(): void 
  {
    this.fetchData.forEach(data => 
    {
      this.dupedData.push(data);
      this.dupedData.push(data);

    });
  }
```

Then simple template.

```
<div *ngFor="let titlee of dupedData">
  {{ titlee }}
</div>
```

Which will give you

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

The following would give the same effectively.

```
<div *ngFor="let titlee of fetchData">
  <div>{{ titlee }}</div>
  <div>{{ titlee }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if it's possible to also do it the other way - aabbcc?

Comment: I was looking for a way without involving typescript, but it might be better so to not make the html too messy

Comment: glad to help :-)