# how can I repeat a fragment of code in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a fragment of html code that has to repeat as many times as it comes from a variable, I tried with a ngFor but it doesn't work for me. 
The variable `quantityPiani` contains a number (integer) that is passed to it by a service

```
<form [formGroup]="formPiano">
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="d-flex alert alert-primary sub-container" *ngFor="let q of quantpiani" role="alert">
      <!-- qui va inserito il ciclo for a seconda della quantità sopra riportata -->
      <div class="scheda">
        <div>
          <h3>PIANO</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h5>Livello del piano:</h5>
          <input type="number" name="" id="piano" formControlName="piano" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h5>quantità stanze:</h5>
          <select formControlName="stanze">
            <option [ngValue]="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div>
  <button [routerLink]="['/ufficio']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Indietro</button>
  <button [routerLink]="['/stanza']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Avanti</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `quantityPiani` should be an array

Comment: What does `quantpiani` contain?

Comment: your are saying fragment of html code for select input?

Comment: if its an array *ngFor should work... It looks like you are using reactive forms are you using a FormArray for that variable? is that the problem?

Comment: `quantpiani` is a number like 4 or 10, I have to repeat that fragment as many times as the number is inside the variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat HTML element multiple times using ngFor based on a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

The `ngFor` works with a collection. So, if you want to use it as a for loop, creating a mock array for the directive is one of the possible ways.

Convert the `quantityPiani` variable to an array which hold symbolic values in your component.

```
quantityPiani = new Array(quantityPiani).fill(0);     //Create an array of quantityPiani number of elements
```

Use this array in your `ngFor` directive:

```
<div class="d-flex alert alert-primary sub-container" *ngFor="let q of quantPiani" role="alert">
```

Note: the caps in the `quantityPiani` variable is corrected in your template code.