# Angular2 ngFor without input array

Tags: angular, ngfor

If there a way to make a loop not over array, but like in C:

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
```

For pagination

Comment: did you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095496/angular-2-how-to-write-a-for-loop-not-a-foreach-loop ?

Comment: Question not quite answered. There is no elegant solution?

Comment: the accepted answer with the index management is the elegant solution.

Comment: @Alex Beugnet what?

Comment: Create pipe which will do all stuff: @Pipe({ name: 'range' })
export class RangePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, exponent: string): Array<number> {
    if (!value || value <= 0) {
      return new Array();
    }
    return (new Array(value)).fill(1);
  }
}