# How to repeat *ngFor a number of times equal to the value of a variable?

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

i'm using Ionic 2 Framework and so Angular 2 and Ts.

In my ts file i have a variable, let's say 'round' and an object 'textblocks'

```
round:number;
textblocks=[{hello:'hi'},{hello:'there'},{hello:'john'},{hello:'doe'}];
```

'Round' value is changing during the life of the application (0 to 3).

Then in my html file, I have a list:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{textblocks[round].hello}}</li>      
</ul>
```

I can use a ngFor to display as much 'li' as the number in the variable 'round', each displaying the text in the corrispondent textblocks[round].hello, with 'round' increasing while the view is used?

Example when round is 1

```
<ul>
  <li>{{textblocks[0].hello}}</li>   
  <li>{{textblocks[1].hello}}</li>      
</ul>
```

that is

- hi
- there

Example when round is 3

```
<ul>
  <li>{{textblocks[0].hello}}</li>   
  <li>{{textblocks[1].hello}}</li> 
  <li>{{textblocks[2].hello}}</li> 
  <li>{{textblocks[3].hello}}</li>       
</ul>
```

- hi
- there
- john
- doe

Comment: Looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number

Comment: nope. I found that answer ,previously, but it doesn't take into account the 'variable' issue. It explains how to repeat an element a fixed amount of times (and the answer are far more complicate than the one provided by trichetriche here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, like so

```
<ul>
    <span *ngFor="let tb of textblocks; let i = index;">
        <li *ngIf="i <= round">{{tb.hello}}</li>
    </span>
</ul>
```

And you can replace the span with a `<template></template>` but I don't remember the exact syntax, so I used a span

Comment: Works perfectly! I wasn't thinking about using a ngIf together! Thank you very much

Comment: No problem, remember to mark it as resolved. By the way, you cant use ngIf and ngFor in the same tag, be careful

Comment: yes, still 4 minutes and I will. What do you mean by using them in the same tag?

Comment: I mean you can't do `<li *ngFor="..."' *ngIf="..."></li>`, this is why I used the span

Comment: Good to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `slice` pipe which is a built-in Angular pipe:

```
<li *ngFor="let textblock of textblocks | slice:0:round">
    {{textblock?.hello}}
</li>
```

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/KizxAHaD70kac2XB2go9?p=preview

Comment: plunker link is broken for me.

Comment: @varunaaruru yup, just fixed it :-) thanks for the notification

Comment: This is a great solution. If you only want to display a number of elements and don't have build in text blocks you can use this reply here in combination: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38249801/1626443