# Angular4: How do I *ngFor, for every number in an int?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-ngfor

I have an int property named "count" in my component.

I would like to display a p tag X amount of times, where X is the int my count property equals. Is there really no simple way to do this, besides messing with fake arrays?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095496/angular-2-how-to-write-a-for-loop-not-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Not possible, you need an object or array for a loop. No way without that type of vars. You could also write an directive to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Yn775KSbBeUPeyaI9sep?p=preview

You can create another variable called countObservable

```
  countObservable = Observable.range(0, this.count).toArray();
```

Use async for in HTML

```
  <p *ngFor="let num of countObservable | async" >Hello {{num}}</h2>
```

**Update**

If we need to update the number we can use `flatMap`.

Instead of above code for countObservable, use this

```
count$= new BehaviorSubject(10);
countObservable$ = 
  this.count$.flatMap(count => Observable.range(0, count).toArray()) ;
```

To change the number value, just update `count$`

```
this.count$.next(newNum);
```

Comment: Funny, I wanted to achieve the functionality for a demo app, where I'm trying to show off a tiny bit of Rxjs knowledge. This is my favorite solution; thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work when I change the count value afterwards. Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to intercept the setting event of you variable and regenerate the observable

Answer (score 6):

You could **easily do it** with an **pipe filter** which transforms an empty array to an number of childs depending on a filter param = number.

#### Pipe filter

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';  

@Pipe({  
    name: 'range',  
    pure: false  
})  

export class RangePipe implements PipeTransform {  
    transform(items: any[], quantity: number): any {  
      items.length = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        items.push(i);
      }
      return items;
    }  
}
```

#### View

```
<div *ngFor="let n of [] | range:100"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I kind of disliked the approach of creating an empty array of size `n` every time that I wanted to render an element `n` times, so I created a custom structural directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, isDevMode, EmbeddedViewRef } from '@angular/core';

export class ForNumberContext {
  constructor(public count: number, public index: number) { }
  get first(): boolean { return this.index === 0; }

  get last(): boolean { return this.index === this.count - 1; }

  get even(): boolean { return this.index % 2 === 0; }

  get odd(): boolean { return !this.even; }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[ForNumber]'
})
export class ForNumberDirective {


 @Input() set forNumberOf(n: number) {
    this._forNumberOf = n;
    this.generate();
  }

  private _forNumberOf: number;

  constructor(private _template: TemplateRef<ForNumberContext>,
    private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input()
  set ngForTemplate(value: TemplateRef<ForNumberContext>) {
    if (value) {
      this._template = value;
    }
  }

  private generate() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this._forNumberOf; i++) {
      this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._template, new ForNumberContext(this._forNumberOf, i));
    }
  }

}
```

And then u can use it as follows:

```
<ng-template ForNumber [forNumberOf]="count" let-index="index">
<span>Iteration: {{index}}!</span></ng-template>
```

Please note, I havent tested it extensively so I cant promise that its bulletproof :)

Comment: This is the solution that fits best with the angular philosophy: it is reusable (unlike the `Observable` solution that has to be duplicated anywhere you want another counter). Does your directive also for with `<span *forNumber="count">...</span>` as a shortcut for the `ng-template`? I think it should be possible to make that work but you might need to change a few things.

Comment: yup, reusability is the reason that I wanted to capsulate this in a directive. I havent tried to use it with the * operator, and there are most likely things to add for change detection. Currently Im using it with an inmutable set of values and I was in a hurry to get the feature working, so I didnt payed attention to all the details

Comment: @Duncan you can now find this and other reusable elements under https://github.com/ngx-extensions/ngx-extensions :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using :

**In TS:**

```
months = [...Array(12).keys()];
```

**In Template:**

```
<p *ngFor="let month of months">{{month+1}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

According Angular documentation:

> `createEmbeddedView()`  Instantiates an embedded view and inserts it into this container. it accepts a context object as second parameter: 
>   `abstract createEmbeddedView(templateRef: TemplateRef, context?: C, index?: number): EmbeddedViewRef`.

When angular creates template by calling createEmbeddedView it can also pass context that will be used inside `ng-template`.

Using context optional parameter, you may use it in the component
extracting it within the template just as you would with the *ngFor.

app.component.html:

```cpp
 <p *for="randomNumber; let i = index; let first = first; let last = last; let even = even, let odd = odd; length = length">
   index :{{i}},
   length:{{length}},
   is first : {{first}},
   is last : {{last}},
   is even : {{even}},
   is odd : {{odd}}
 </p>
```

for.directive.ts:

```cpp
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[for]'
})
export class ForDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input('for') set loop(num: number) {
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
        this.templateRef,
        {
          index: i,
          odd: i % 2 == 1,
          even: i % 2 == 0,
          first: i == 0,
          last: i == num,
          length: num - 1,
        }
      );
  }
}
```